# Insert multiple records in mongodb using express

Tags: mongodb, express

```
let countries = [ {
{
      code: "1",
      sortname: "US",
      name: "USA"
    },
{
}...
} ]

countries.forEach(country => {
    let mycountry = new Countries({
      mycountry.code : country.code,
      mycountry.name : country.name,
      mycountry.sortname : country.sortname
    })
    await mycountry.save();
  })
  res.json({success: true});
```

How to insert multiple records into mongodb using express. Please guide on this

Comment: have u connected with the database? what is the error?

Comment: Make sure you elaborate the question with relevant example or the desired output. for instance, here, are you searching for a way to bulk insert data into the DB?

Comment: Yes I do have multiple data that need to insert into db I tried that way but getting _Countries.Countries is not a constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting probably you did not import model properly after that change, you can try this code

```
let mycountry = '';
  countries.forEach(country => {
      mycountry = new Countries({
      code : country.code,
      name : country.name,
      country_id : country.country_id
    })   
    mycountry.save();
     
  })
  
 res.json({success: true});
```